# Loop to avoid repetitive code

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
myApp.onPageInit("page", function(page) {
    $$('#ajax_step1').on('submitted', function(e) {
        mainView.router.loadPage('transfer1');
    });

    $$('#ajax_step2').on('submitted', function(e) {
        mainView.router.loadPage('transfer2');
    });
    ...
});
```

The code inside the function seems very repetitive. How can i do the same but in a more smart way?

I tried something like this, but will not work as exptected.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    $$('#ajax_step'+i).on('submitted', function(e) {
        mainView.router.loadPage('transfer'+i);
    });
}
```

Comment: Although your chosen method makes this question a duplicate, I would recommend having a `data-targetpage="transfer1"` attribute on your form thing, then use that attribute to determine where to go next. Use a class to bind events.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that's exactly why I re-opened this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$$('[id^=ajax_step]').on('submitted', function(e) {
    mainView.router.loadPage('transfer'+this.id.slice(9));
});
```

`'[id^=ajax_step]'` selects all elements whose id starts with "ajax_step".

Answer (score 4):

A better approach is to use common classes along with `data` attributes containing meta data relevant to a specific element instance. Try something like this:

```
<div class="ajax_step" data-transfer="transfer1"></div>
```

```js
myApp.onPageInit("page", function(page) {
    $$('.ajax_step').on('submitted', function(e) {
        mainView.router.loadPage($(this).data('transfer'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Most of the times, this is the right approach, I agree with that.